# How to use react, router, redux, and react-intl together?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-intl

We have been using react, react router, and redux.  Now we want to add injectIntl.  I am getting a problem with my syntax and hoping you could help.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { intlShape, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

...

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent));
```

and I changed it to be

```
export default injectIntl(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)));
```

The error is

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

What do I need to do to combine all these frameworks?

Comment: The problem might be more to do with `MyComponent` rather than using all these dependencies together. What does `MyComponent` look like?

Answer (score 0):

It looks `injectIntl` doesn't hoist / copy the statics of the wrapped component and it's very possible reason of the problem.

Reacts docs says [Static Methods Must Be Copied Over](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over) :

> When you apply a HOC to a component, though, the original component is
>   wrapped with a container component. That means the new component does
>   not have any of the static methods of the original component.

You can check the [already reported issue](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1047) in `injectIntl` tracker.

**There's a workaround**, while the fix is officially applied to the project.

You can create a wrapper of `injectIntl`, that copies the statics correctly:

```
// utils/injectIntl.js

import { injectIntl as baseInjectIntl } from 'react-intl';
import hoistNonReactStatic from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

/**
 * A fixed injectIntl that hoists statics.
 */
export function injectIntl(WrappedComponent: Function): Function {
  const WrapperComponent = baseInjectIntl(WrappedComponent);

  hoistNonReactStatic(WrapperComponent, WrappedComponent);

  return WrapperComponent;
}
```

And later use it in your app, as follows:

```
import injectIntl from 'utils/injectIntl'

// ...

injectIntl(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)));
```

[Credits](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1047#issuecomment-343414226).

Comment: I gave this a try, and I get the same error message.

Comment: Now I see that `react-intl` docs says that you **must** use the provider component `<IntlProvider>`. Here are [implementation details](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki#creating-an-i18n-context). You can try and please let me know if it works.

Comment: So before using `injectIntl`, you should firstly wrap your Root / App component with `<IntlProvider>`.

Comment: [I posted another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50715922/4312466), that describes the must usage of `<IntlProvider>`

Answer (score -1):

Before using `injectIntl`, you should firstly wrap your Root / App component with `<IntlProvider>`.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <IntlProvider
        locale={usersLocale}
        messages={translationsForUsersLocale}
    >
        <App/>
    </IntlProvider>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here's what the [`react-intl` docs](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki#creating-an-i18n-context) says:

> **Creating an I18n Context**
>
> React Intl uses the provider pattern to scope an i18n context to a
>   tree of components. This allows configuration like the current locale
>   and set of translated strings/messages to be provided at the root of a
>   component tree and made available to the `<Formatted*>` components. This
>   is the same concept as what Flux frameworks like Redux use to provide
>   access to a store within a component tree.
>
> **All apps using React Intl must use the `<IntlProvider>` component.**
>
> The most common usage is to wrap your root React component with
>   `<IntlProvider>` and configure it with the user's current locale and the
>   corresponding translated strings/messages

Comment: Redux also have a provider